# Prevent same product name to appear several times - ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've got a (simplified) with 3 columns:
Offer_name / Product_Name/ Offer_rating

I want to display, thanks to AMPScript, the best rated offered in my newsletter. However, I do not want to display a Product_Name twice.

I used the "de-duplicate row" code by https://sprignaturemoves.com/de-duplicate-rows-ampscript/ 
But instead of ordering my rows by Product_Name, I have to do it by Offer_rating 
The results is that I can have the same Product_Name displayed several times in my email. 
This is because only the prevproductname is stored and I would need to store prevproductname1, prevproductname2, etc. 
 
Having a

> @prevproduct@i

doesn't seem to work so I am a little stuck there.

Does any body had had the same issue?

Here are a sample of data ordered by offer_rating :

---

[image: data sample and wanted output]

---

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data your are retrieving and how you'd like it to show in the email.

Comment: The solution on my blog only de-duplicates by the column you're sorting by in the lookup.

Comment: Hi, I just added data sample and wanted output in my post

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, below is the best I can do to help solve your issue:

```
%%[
var @i, @rows, @row, @OfferRating, @prevOfferRating, @productName, @prevProductName, @rowsToReturn

var @rowsToReturn = 0 /* up to 2000 */

SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SubscriberProducts" ,@rowsToReturn, "OrderRating asc", "EmailAddress",emailaddr)

set @prevOfferRating = ""

FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO

  set @row = Row(@rows,@i)
  set @OfferRating = Field(@row, "OfferRating")


  if empty(@prevOfferRating) or @OfferRating != @prevOfferRating then

     set @prevOfferRating = @OfferRating

     set @rows2 = LookupOrderedRows("SubscriberProducts" ,1, "productName asc", "EmailAddress",emailaddr)

        set @row2 = Row(@rows2,1)
        set @productName = Field(@row2, "productName")

        if empty(@prevProductName) or @productName != @prevProductName then

            set @prevProductName = @ProductName

        ]%%

            <h1>%%=v(@ProductName)=%%: %%=v(@OfferRating)=%%</h1>

        %%[ endif ]%%

    %%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%
```

What this does is runs through two FOR statements with 2 IF statements to ensure both the Rate and Product are Unique. I have not tested it, but in theory it should handle this.

As the initial lookup is Order Rate asc meaning all dups should be in a row and as the productName (put to single item return based on Offer Rate and reduce render time) combined with an IF statement, it should limit the product name to a single instance as well.

This might need some tweaking to make it exactly fit into your needs, but it should at least lead you into the right direction.